# Gradle Plugin Spock Testing

Tags: gradle, spock

I'm writing a plugin for Gradle 2.3 which includes Groovy 2.3.9, and I am attempting to test it using Spock 1.0-groovy-2.3. I'm getting the following error because Spock is trying to use Groovy 2.3.10.

The important bit.

```
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Conflicting module versions. Module [groovy-all is loaded in version 2.3.9 and you are trying to load version 2.3.10
```

The "complete" stack trace.

```
Failed to instantiate spec 'PluginTest'
org.spockframework.util.InternalSpockError: Failed to instantiate spec 'PluginTest'
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.createSpecInstance(BaseSpecRunner.java:113)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.run(BaseSpecRunner.java:65)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.Sputnik.run(Sputnik.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:360)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.isValidWeakMetaClass(ClassInfo.java:221)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClassForClass(ClassInfo.java:191)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClass(ClassInfo.java:236)
    at com.trxi.oracle.PluginTest.$getStaticMetaClass(PluginTest.groovy)
    at com.trxi.oracle.PluginTest.<init>(PluginTest.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.createSpecInstance(BaseSpecRunner.java:107)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Conflicting module versions. Module [groovy-all is loaded in version 2.3.9 and you are trying to load version 2.3.10
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl$DefaultModuleListener.onModule(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:509)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.ExtensionModuleScanner.scanExtensionModuleFromProperties(ExtensionModuleScanner.java:77)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.ExtensionModuleScanner.scanExtensionModuleFromMetaInf(ExtensionModuleScanner.java:71)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.ExtensionModuleScanner.scanClasspathModules(ExtensionModuleScanner.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:71)
    at groovy.lang.GroovySystem.<clinit>(GroovySystem.java:33)
    ... 38 more
```

The dependencies section of my build.gradle file.

```
dependencies {
    compile gradleApi()
    compile localGroovy()
    testCompile "org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.3"
}
```

Is there a way to configure gradleApi() to use Groovy 2.3.10 (or 2.4.3 for Spock 1.0-groovy-2.4) OR to configure Spock 1.0-groovy-2.3 to use Groovy 2.3.9?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can exclude transitive dependencies brought in by spock to solve this version conflict. try:

```groovy
dependencies {
    compile gradleApi()
    compile localGroovy()
    testCompile ("org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.3") {
        exclude module: "groovy-all"
    }
}
```